# Can't do POST request to a dotnet web api using flutter web app

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, asp.net-core-webapi

So when I try to do a POST request to a dotnet web API from flutter web using Dio package, I  got this error after a while:

[image: XMLHttpRequest error.]

In Android, the post request hits the endpoint successfully, but not in flutter web.

**Flutter POST request:**

```
Future<Response<dynamic>> test(String email, String password) async {
    if (dio.httpClientAdapter is DefaultHttpClientAdapter) {
      (dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
          (HttpClient client) {
        client.badCertificateCallback =
            (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
        return client;
      };
    }
    try {
      final response = await dio.post(('https://10.0.2.2:5001/users/sign-in'),
          data: {"email": email, "password": password},
          options: Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
            HttpHeaders.accessControlAllowOriginHeader: "*",
          }));
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I've read online that this could be an error related to CORS but I've already configured CORS in my API server and still not works:

**API StartUp.cs (C#)**
Configure services:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
```

Configure:

```
    app.UseCors();
```

Have someone had a similar issue? Am I configuring wrong the CORS in my API? Do think that using dart's http would be a better approach?

Comment: please look to your chrome console. or your webconsole.if you have cors or other error .it will suggest there please check

Comment: @lava Browser's console just show that there was a a time out `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` after 30 seconds

If I change 10.0.2.2 for localhost in POST's uri error change to `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` but this one responds instantly

Answer (score 0):

Change

https://**10.0.2.2**:5001/users/sign-in

to

https://**localhost**:5001/users/sign-in

localhost won't work on android

android converts 10.0.2.2 to localhost